# IIS 7.0 is running single-thread

Tags: iis, iis-7

I've seen that in IIS 7.0 each site has only one single-thread (if two users open two different links on the same site, the second user can't view his page until the first user finishes loading his page).
This not happen with sites on IIS 7.5

It's possibile to change this behavior?